# Why can't I train like a dataset of samples instead of maintaining replay buffer?

Tags: deep-rl, algorithm, ddpg, experience-replay

On observing the [DDPG algorithm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.02971.pdf#page=5), we notice that the updation of neural networks is happening *during* the episode.

But, it seems there is no issue if we allow the completion of an episode and then treat the *buffer as a dataset* to update the neural networks *if I don't have any memory constraints*. Isn't it?

Even if the episode is too long, I think we can update neural networks once an episode terminates if I have enough memory. I don't think memory constraint is a reason for updating neural networks during episodes, as we can see large datasets in deep learning competitions and research. One possible reason I am thinking is that an episode [may not have a goal state](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/30087/18758) and can continue indefinitely.

> **In general MDPs do not have goal states**. Although using the agent's
> actions to achieve certain desirable end states, such as winning a
> game or completing a puzzle, is a very common design, there is no
> requirement for this. The more general requirement is to maximise some
> aggregate of the reward at each time step - usually either a
> discounted sum of rewards or the mean reward.

If 'having no goal state(s)' is a reason for using buffer, why do the authors claim it as an *algorithm* instead of a procedure? Am I missing something?